# CMake fails with "IMPORTED_IMPLIB not set for imported target ...", for OpenCV Debug

Tags: c++, opencv, cmake

**My Environment:**

- OpenCV (4.8.0)
- CMake 3.26.4
- Windows10
- Generator: Visual Studio 16 (2019)
- IDE: VSCode

I recently compiled OpenCV from source (with CUDA), both Release, and Debug configurations since I want to use it in my application.

I will start by mentioned that for precompiled binaries of OpenCV everything works, and also for the (compiled from source) Release configuration, it seems everything is fine and well, CMake configures the project correctly, and compilation succeeds (+linking and running). However, I am running into multiple problems when trying to configure the project with the Debug configuration.

I am using the commands:

```
find_package(OpenCV 4.8.0 EXACT REQUIRED PATHS "${OPENCV_PATH_ROOT}") 

... later on ...

target_link_libraries(myproject PRIVATE ${OpenCV_LIBS})
```

Where ${OPENCV_PATH_ROOT} points to the install folder of the debug version (i.e. where the bin, etc, include,and x64 folders are).

When configuring the project using CMake, it throws the following error for many if not all of the modules:

```
CMake Error in CMakeLists.txt:
[cmake]   IMPORTED_IMPLIB not set for imported target "opencv_calib3d" configuration
[cmake]   "MinSizeRel".

... later on ...

[cmake] CMake Error in CMakeLists.txt:
[cmake]   IMPORTED_IMPLIB not set for imported target "opencv_objdetect"
[cmake]   configuration "RelWithDebInfo".
```

What am I doing wrong here? the project configuration is definitely set to Debug and not "MinSizeRel" or "RelWithDebInfo", and when compiling OpenCV the flag "BUILD_WITH_DEBUG_INFO" was set to false for both the Debug and Release configurations. Is this a mistake? The official documentation for the CMAKE flags do not mention this should be turned on unless I wish to have debug symbols for the Release version, which I don't.

Also, it is worth mentioning I am by no means some CMake expert, so I might be missing on something essential.

Comment: Which [CMake generator](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generators.7.html) do you use? Visual Studio provides both *compiler* and *generator*. The latter one is *multi configuration* generator, that is it configures the project for all configurations at once.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I am using the Visual Studio 16 (2019) generator (edited question to reflect this).